# CGLIB 3 in Maven Central

Tags: maven, dependencies, cglib

So, [CGLIB 3 has been out](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cglib/files/cglib3/) for a few months and it looks like Spring 3.2 [is now working with it as well](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9669) - not sure however why it's [not on Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22cglib%22%20AND%20a%3a%22cglib%22).

Is there another Maven Repository where this dependency exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a direct answer to your question but it may help you: [Spring 3.2 is inlining CGLIB 3](http://blog.springsource.org/2012/12/13/spring-framework-3-2-goes-ga/). No need for a dependency on CGLIB anymore...